# Database Vs Filesystem

Tags: database, file-io

I have to maintain the number of user visits for each module of my app. What will be the best option: simple file write or database inserts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either way really should work depending on your implementation of how you write the file. However I would prefer to use [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) just because its pretty quick and it does not have that much overhead.

Comment: Thanks John; Already my app is using mysql database. My idea is to insert each request into a requests table, and process this requests table for module wise visits calculation using a cron for every 15min. will it works?

Comment: Are you going to delete the request object after you have determined which module was visited?

Comment: There are also a number of external queues that you could use as well.  What this would allow you to do is write the request to the queue then remove it after it has been processed and then increment the number of visits per module.  Then you can cut down on the io with your SQLite database.

Comment: Hi Jon, Yes I'm planning to delete the request object from the primary table after processing it for summary. In your next comment, you said using queue instead of my primary `requests` table, that is very interesting for me. can you explain how to maintain this queue between the client requests?

Comment: You could maintain it the same as you way that you were planning to in your earlier comment.  You have threads that wake up every 15 minutes (or some other time interval depending on use) then pull the requests off of the queue, process them and then write to the database.

Comment: You could also just have a thread or threads that are constantly checking the queue for new requests.  I am not sure of how many requests you will tend to get or the resources available to this application.

Comment: Hi John, I'm clear about the processing the queued requests, but my concern is how to maintain the queue between the different client calls?

Comment: I am a little confused with what your concerns are over maintaining the queue.   Could you give me some examples of what these are?

Comment: Hi John, my concern what exactly the `queue` in your answer? is it a java object to hold the http client requests?

Comment: No, I was thinking it could be an external queue similar to your database.  For example you could use something similar to memcache.  Then, you periodically wake up, and query it for any new requests.

Answer (score 1):

I would always go with a database. In a database you are able to create custom reports on user visits using the power of SQL (or another other query language). With a flat file system you would have to create your own bespoke reporting solution to feedback results, effectively building your own database and querying system.

Say for example you used a database (mysql, sql server, oracle, sqlite) and for every visit you recorded a timestamp with the module id e.g.

```
timestamp,module_id
2010-01-04 10:00:00,1
2010-02-06 10:27:30,2
.
.
.
2011-04-15 18:22:00,5
```

You would be able to report on the total number of visits for all modules and you could also write a query to find all visits between January 2010 - March 2010 for module 2.

Using a database is also more future friendly, if this a live project, there is always a chance you will want to gain more statistics about your application usage e.g. geographical location of user. Altering your database to store this is very easy, you just alter the table to include a new row and set the default value to something like 'Not known' for all existing records where you did not have this functionality built. You can then write new reporting queries to give you the new information.

So basically in summary, a database is vastly superior. The ONLY downside I see is that it is slightly more resource intensive for a small project that will not grow in reporting scope, but considering today's average computer this really isn't an issue at all!